# From a mobile device, how do you launch MS Remote Desktop client that's already been downloaded?

Tags: android, iphone, windows-mobile, detect, rdp

I have an html page with a button that detects what type of mobile device the user is on, then directs them to the download page for Microsoft Remote Desktop Client. After downloading, the button click should detect that RDP has already been downloaded and launch it. How to write this in an html page?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to launch another application in iOS is through a schema.If the other application doesn't provide such schema, there's nothing you can do about it.

if it does have it, you'd do

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL urlWithString:@"schemagoeshere://paramsIfAny"]];
```

Comment: Thanks. I think this link provided what I was looking for, but am still testing; http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn690096.aspx